# Interpreting git status output after automatic merge failures

Tags: git

I have a git repo called `myapp` that has a `develop` branch and several (in progress) feature branches, including the one I'm working on, `feature/one`.

My `feature/one` branch was cut from a freshly-pulled `develop` about a week ago, but `develop` has been updated several times since then. I just ran `git merge develop` on my `feature/one` branch, and noticed that some automatic merges failed:

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So I ran a `git status` and see:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/one
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/one' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:

  <whole bunch of stuff here I'm omitting for brevity!>

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   src/main/java/com/myapp/Fizz.java
    deleted by us:   src/main/java/com/myapp/Buzz.java
    both modified:   src/test/java/com/myapp/Foobar.java
```

I'm new to this, but I'm **interpreting** this to mean:

1. That in my local `feature/one` branch, I deleted `Fizz.java` and `Buzz.java`, but because they were still present on the `develop` branch when I merged them in, git added them back in for me. And, furthermore, since I do actually want them to be deleted, I need to re-delete them on `feature/one`; and
2. Both recent changes to `develop` and my `feature/one` modified the same `Foobar.java` file, and so I need to inspect the changes manually and resolve the merge conflicts myself.

Am I interpreting this output correctly, and if not, what is git actually telling me?! Was my choice to use `git status` to view the automatic merge failures correct or is there a better way to see what failed and what might need further attention? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. That in my local feature/one branch, I deleted `Fizz.java` and `Buzz.java`, but because they were still present on the `develop` branch when I merged them in, git added them back in for me.

More or less, but not *precisely*, and precision matters here.  As Edward Thomson said, someone else must have also *changed* those files.  We'll get to the precise definition of this in a moment.

> And, furthermore, since I do actually want them to be deleted, I need to re-delete them on `feature/one`

This is another area where precision becomes important.  The answer here is probably yes.  As before, phrasing matters.

> 2. Both recent changes to `develop` and my `feature/one` modified the same `Foobar.java` file, and so I need to inspect the changes manually and resolve the merge conflicts myself.

Yes.

> Was my choice to use git status to view the automatic merge failures correct or is there a better way to see what failed and what might need further attention?

The `git status` output is as good as it gets for post-mortem analysis, *unless* you still have the output that happened *during* the merge.  This is all a bit unfortunate since the `git status` output isn't really as good as it should be.

To understand what Git status is showing, and why, and fill in all the precision-y bits, we need to dive into the topic of how `git merge` really works, what Git does with its *index*—both normally, and in the special case of a conflicted merge—and how `git status` presents a view of what's *in* the index.

#### The goal of a merge is to combine work

As you mentioned:

> My `feature/one` branch was cut from a freshly-pulled `develop` about a week ago, but develop has been updated several times since then.

That is, if we were to draw the commit graph—the data structure one gets by viewing the connections *between* commits, because each commit remembers its immediate predecessor(s)—we'd have a drawing that looks like this:

```
            C <-D <-F <-H   <-- feature/one (HEAD)
           /
... <-A <-B
           \
            E <-G   <-- origin/develop
```

That is, your name `feature/one` identifies your newest commit `H`, which points back to your earlier commit `F`, which points back to `D`, and so on.  The updates you've gotten from the other Git mean that your remote-tracking name `origin/develop` now points to commit `G`, which points back to `E`, which points back to `B`, and so on.

Git can and does use this graph to figure out which earlier commit you both started from.  This commit is called the *merge base*, and in our drawing here—which uses uppercase letters to stand in for actual commit hash IDs—that's commit `B`.

Each commit holds a full, complete snapshot of the entire project.  This project has at least three files (and probably more) in `B`.  Many or most of those same files are in the snapshot in `G`, which we can call "theirs".  Many of those same files are also in the snapshot `H`, which we can call "ours", but `Fizz.java` and `Buzz.java` are *not* in `H`.

#### To combine work, we need to compare commits

Once Git has identified the merge base commit, it needs to figure out what you did, and what they did.  To find changes, Git uses (an internal version of) `git diff` (the front end `git diff` is the user-facing display variant).  So Git will run, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-H>   # what we did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-G>   # what they did
```

Each diff listing may include actions like *removed `Fizz.java`* or *modified `Foobar.java`.*  It can also include renames.  (Git doesn't actually *record* renames, it just *computes* them from diffing the two snapshots.  Fortunately there are few or no renames here to complicate the picture, so we get to ignore this.)

Git must now *combine* the two sets of changes.  The combined changes will be applied to the snapshot that's in the *base* commit, to get everything ready for the *next* commit ... and now is a good time to have an aside on how Git really builds commits.

#### The index and its role in commits

Commits contain frozen snapshots—your project's files—plus some frozen metadata: who made the commit, when, why (its log message), and that all-important *parent commit hash* that forms the graph we drew above when locating the merge base commit.  Because the files *in* a commit are (a) frozen and (b) in a special, compressed, Git-only format, they're only actually useful to Git itself.  That's fine for archiving and various other purposes, but no good for making progress.  We need a way to *work on* and *work with* the files.

For this, Git gives us the *work tree* (or work-tree or working tree or working directory, or some other variant of these spellings).  Here, our files have their everyday normal format, and we can read them and write them and get work done.  No big deal so far, right?  There are two copies of each file: the frozen one from the current commit, plus the work one.  Other version control systems stop here: they have the frozen committed files, and the work-tree files.  (The frozen copies can be shared across many or even all commits, which is safe because they're frozen.)

Git is ... different.  Partly to make everything go really fast, Git keeps a *third* copy of each file (though it keeps them in the frozen format here, internally, and winds up re-using the frozen copy initially).  Git calls this the *index*, and what's in the index is not *quite* frozen—it's more sort of slushy, ready-to-freeze.

In particular, you can *replace* any index copy of any file with a newly-snapshotted copy taken from the work-tree (or from any other existing commit, or anywhere really).  Running `git add` copies (and compresses and Git-ifies) a work-tree file and puts the updated file into the index, where it is now ready to be committed.  That is, the index copy now matches the work-tree copy instead of the `HEAD` commit copy: it's *staged for commit*.

Meanwhile `git reset` works by copying the frozen file from the current commit back into the index.  The `git reset` command has a *lot* of operating modes, so it can do more things, or avoid resetting the index, or do rather different things, but this is one of its main jobs: copying frozen files from the `HEAD` commit back into the index, to *unstage* them.

In the end, what this means is that *at all times*, the index has *all your files* ready to be put into the next commit, all Git-ified and ready to be frozen into a commit.  Well, we should say *almost* all times, because during a merge, the index takes on an expanded role.  But otherwise, the index is, in effect, the *next commit you will make*, or at least, the proposed one minus the metadata: it does not yet have your name, a timestamp, a log message, and so on.  But it's still the proposed next *snapshot*, at least.

When you run `git commit`, Git mostly *ignores* the work-tree (though it will by default run a quick `git status` for you and stick that into your commit message as comments you can use while composing your log message).  It's going to take whatever is in the *index*, and use that for the new commit.  The work-tree is irrelevant: what matters is the index.

#### The role of the index during a merge

To make room for merges, the files in the index are normally in what Git calls *stage zero*.  Each file has up to four stage numbers, or as I like to call them, staging slots.  Slot zero is used for a normal everyday non-conflicted file.  Slot 1 is reserved for a copy of a file taken from the *merge base* commit, slot 2 for a file from *our* commit, and slot 3 for a file from *their* commit, all as seen during a merge operation.

More precisely, though we won't get into all the details here, these three higher stage numbers are used during what I like to call the *to merge* part of a merge, or *merge as a verb*.  When you run `git merge`, it has several main parts.  One is locating a suitable merge base.  One is where most of the action happens and where things stop with conflicts, and that's the *to merge* or verb-y part of merging.  The last is to make a *merge commit*, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective instead of a verb.

Anyway, when the *to merge* or merge-as-a-verb action happens, Git uses the three higher staging slots to hold the three copies of each file that go into the merge.  If Git is able to complete the merge entirely on its own, Git will `git add` the final result file on its own too.  That *removes* the higher-stage entries, leaving instead a normal stage-zero entry for the file, ready to be committed.

When Git *can't* complete the merge on its own, it leaves the higher stage entries behind.  It also leaves a copy of the file in the work-tree.  This means instead of the usual three copies (HEAD + index + work-tree), you now have four or five copies, depending on how you want to count: there's the `HEAD` version, but also the stages 1-3 versions, plus the work-tree file.  Normally the stage 2 version *is* the `HEAD` version, so that's how I count four copies of each file: three stages (stage 1 = base, stage 2 / HEAD = ours, and stage 3 = theirs) plus work-tree.  (Git also leaves a file named `MERGE_HEAD` around, which points to the "theirs" commit and hence matches the stage 3 entries.)

#### When there are no deleted or renamed files, it's a little easier (and more usual)

For a file like `Foobar.java`—modified in both `--ours` and `--theirs` versions with respect to the common starting version in the merge base—we have those three original copies in the index, plus Git's best effort at combining them sitting in the work-tree.  Git stops doing the merge, leaving three file versions recorded in the index at nonzero stages, and the messy merge result in the work-tree (and some extra internal information, in particular two files named `MERGE_HEAD` and `MERGE_MSG`, inside `.git` to remember how to finish the merge later).

The work-tree copy has conflict markers in it, so you may be able to resolve the merge using only the work-tree copy.  If so, you `git add` the fixed-up work-tree copy, and `git add` removes the slot 1-2-3 entries and puts in the correctly merged (by you) copy at slot zero, where it's ready to go.

#### With deleted files, there's an empty slot

For a file like `Fizz.java`, though, there was a *high level* conflict, that occurred before Git even got around to looking at the contents *within* the file.  The high level conflict in this case is:

- they (`B` vs `G`) *changed* the file
- you (`B` vs `H`) *deleted* the file

This is a `modify/delete conflict` and `git merge` says so.  Having said so, Git stops the merge as before, but this time leaves only *two* index slots occupied: slot 1 holds the merge base version and slot 3 holds theirs, while slot 2 is *empty*.  You don't have a `Fizz.java` file, so the slot is left empty to note that, well, you didn't have a `Fizz.java` file.

Git will, for this case, leave *their* version of `Fizz.java` in the work-tree (and in slot 3 of course).  This is, as before, irrelevant to Git itself: `git commit` will use whatever you put into slot zero.  Your job now is to figure out what that is.  Once you figure it out, you can `git add` or `git rm` to get rid of the items in slots 1 and 3 and put the correct item—or lack of item—into slot zero.

#### Committing the merge

Once you have resolved everything and put the right files into all the slot-zero entries in the index, you run either `git merge --continue` or simply `git commit`.  Both do the same thing—in fact, `git merge --continue` just notices the recorded `MERGE_*` files and runs `git commit` for you, and `git commit` notices the recorded `MERGE_*` files and makes the commit as a merge commit.

Git then builds the commit contents in the usual way, except for one thing: the new commit has not one but *two* parents.  The first parent is the current (`HEAD`) commit as usual, and the second parent is the commit you merged:

```
          C--D--F--H--I   <-- feature/one (HEAD)
         /           /
...--A--B           /
         \         /
          E-------G   <-- origin/develop
```

This extra parent is what makes the new commit a merge commit.  Having made the commit, Git updates the branch name `feature/one` to point to it, just as it would for any ordinary non-merge commit.

(Note that `git commit` will refuse to complete the job until all remaining index entries are at stage zero.)

#### `git status` compares `HEAD`, the index, and the work-tree

At any point—before, during, or after the merge—you can run `git status`.  Besides printing some statistics about which branch name `HEAD` is attached-to, it:

- compares the `HEAD` commit to what's in the index (`git diff --name-status` style)
- compares what's in the index to what's in the work-tree (also `git diff --name-status` style)

It notices whether there are entries in slots 1-3 and calls those *unmerged*.  For other files, which are at stage zero, it tells you if they're different in `HEAD`-vs-index—these are *staged for commit*—and/or if they are different in index-vs-work-tree, which are *not staged for commit*.

It's that simple (if anything in Git is simple): `git status` sees, and uses, what is in the index, and compares that to `HEAD` and to work-tree.  If you're still in the middle of a conflicted merge, it sees nonzero staging slots, and guesses, based on what's in the three slots, which files are "deleted by us" or "deleted by them" (and gets this wrong in tricky rename cases!).  If you've resolved everything, it notices the leftover `MERGE_*` files that mean you need to finish the merge, and tells you so.

#### Conclusion

The `git status` output is a summary of what's in your *index*.  Since the index is what will go into your *next* commit, that tells you a lot about it:

- Nonzero stage entries mean you *can't* commit yet (nor even complete an internal `git write-tree` operation, really).
- If slots 1-3 of some name are in use, those are the three copies that went into the merge operation, which stopped due to conflicts: high level ones (files reshuffled) and/or low-level ones (files matched up but our changes conflicted with their changes).
- If some slots are unfilled, the base, ours, and/or theirs versions of the files aren't there, or are under some other *name* in the index.  This last is where `git status` is not really quite adequate, because in tricky files-were-renamed cases, there's not *enough* information *in* the index to reconstruct what `git merge` told you about the high level rename conflicts.
- If everything is at stage zero, commit is possible.  Then the comparison to `HEAD` tell you what *will* be different if you commit now, and the comparison to the work-tree tells you what *could be* different if you would just use `git add` to copy from work-tree to index.

Answer (score 0):

> That in my local feature/one branch, I deleted Fizz.java and Buzz.java, but because they were still present on the develop branch when I merged them in, git added them back in for me.

No, they weren't merely *present*, they were actually *changed* on the other branch.  Had those files not been changed then your deletion would not have been a conflict (the files would simply be removed in the merge result without bothering you.)

You can delete them again, but you need to be aware that you're removing somebody else's changes when you do so.

> Both recent changes to develop and my feature/one modified the same Foobar.java file, and so I need to inspect the changes manually and resolve the merge conflicts myself.

Correct.  Git has updated `Foobar.java` with the merge information and provided conflict markers.  For example:

```
This is a file
that will be
involved in a merge.

<<<<<<< HEAD
This is a change in
"my" branch.
=======
Here's a conflicting
change in the "master"
branch.
>>>>>>> master

You'll need to choose
the best changes and
resolve the conflict.
```

The information in *your* branch is between the `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` lines.  The information in the *other* branch is between the `=======` and `>>>>>>> master` lines.  Choose how to include both changes, save the file and continue.